# Fatal error: git init

Tags: git, fatal-error

```
fatal: cannot use /Users/myname/ as an exclude file
```

I get this error whenever I try to type the command `git init`, it gives me the above error. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `.gitconfig` in your home directory. You almost guaranteed have the line

```
exclude /Users/myname/
```

in it

Comment: it would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted if it was accurate, so others that have the same issue can find it more easily in the future